# Nav Dropdown - Hover and Click

Tags: jquery, html, css, less

I have a nav, on rollover a sub nav appears.

This also needs to work on mobile so I'm thinking the best way to achieve this is by using jquery on click. So it'll appear when hovered on - on desktop and on click - on mobile.

I've implemented this solution but the problem is, when a user hovers on the nav, then clicks it, the nav stays on even on hover off.

What's the best solution for this?

I'm using bootstrap 2.

HTML

```
<ul>
<li class="n1">Nav 1</li>
<li class="n2">Nav 2</li>
<li class="n3">Nav 3
    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li>DropDown 1</li>
        <li>DropDown 2</li>
        <li>DropDown 3</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

LESS

```
ul{
    li{
        &:last-child{

                &:hover {
                    border-bottom-color: white;
                    .nav-dropdown{
                        display: block;
                    }
                }
            }
      }
 }
```

JS

```
$('.dropdown').parent().on('click', function(){
        $('dropdown').toggle();
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way would be to include modernizr.js in your page and detect if the page is viewed on the touch-enabled device. If so you can add proper jQuery code.

You can read more detailed article on http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/detect-touch-device-modernizr/